# Trying to override Table Row settings

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm using these rules

```
#MyTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
}

#MyTable tr:nth-child(even) {
}
```

I'm trying to put a table inside one of the rows:

```
#InnerTable {
}
```

But it seems to be inhereting the style of MyTable. How do I override The MyTable settings for my inner table so that it has no effect on InnerTable's style?

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/PLyzK/

You could rewrite your existing rules to be more specific. Using the child selector you could have:

```
#MyTable > tr:nth-child(odd) {}
#MyTable > tr:nth-child(event) {}
```

This limits the rule to `tr` elements which are directly contained within an element with the id `#MyTable`. Then you can add specific rules for your `#InnerTable` as well:

```
#InnerTable > tr:nth-child(odd) {}
#InnerTable > tr:nth-child(event) {}
```

The `E > F` selector "Matches any F element that is a child of an element E" whereas the normal `E F` would "Match any F element that is a descendant of an E element".

Bare in mind that if your `tr` are in fact contained within a `tbody` element as they should be to create a valid `table` element,

```
<table id="MyTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The your rules would have to reflect this:

```
#MyTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {}
#MyTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(event) {}

#InnerTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {}
#InnerTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(event) {}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/PLyzK/

---

Or you could specifically reset all options in a rule applied later on (avoid if possible, since this leads to a lot of meaningless repetition):

```
#MyTable #SomeOtherTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
    some-property: the-default;
}
```

For more ideas on how to be more specific (reducing the set of elements your rules will apply to) [check out the W3C documentation regarding selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching).

Comment: +1 note that the child selector does not work in IE6. But so does `nth-child` so you're in the clear

Comment: I just tried this, and though the inner table kept its own style, it removed all the styling from my odd and even rows. Thats not what im looking for. I want the rows to keep their style while the inner has its own

Comment: @WillingLearner CSS is cascading, there is no way to not inherit certain properties of the parent, such as font and colour. You need to be more specific on your question regarding the exact elements your wish to effect and the properties involved.

Comment: @marcus whybrow: Not sure how much more specific i can get than i already have. I want the columns and rows of my inner table to have their own style instead of the parent tables row styles. The inner table should have its own margins, paddings, borders, colors, fonts, etc.

Comment: @marcus whybrow: Please view:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779192/help-me-override-table-style-on-nested-inner-table

Comment: @WillingLearner I have modified my answer to hopefully clarify the usage which will give you the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!
If you just try to specify a class for the td, it only works on every other row.. to make it work everywhere, in the css file, add the keyword !important
for example:

```
.correct {
    background-color:#C9FDC1 !important}    
.incorrect {
    background-color:#FDB5B7 !important}
```

Do this at the bottom of your css file, after the nth child rule.
The on your table, use td class="correct"  or td class="incorrect"