# Override table style on nested inner table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Please view my js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WillingLearner/gzYPU/7/

As you can clearly see when you run the fiddle, the inner table with the border is not displaying its own styles. Its inheriting the style from the parent.

Please help me display the inner table with its own styles only, while still remaining nested in the parent table row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to fix your problem. You have two styles on `tr`:

```
#MainTable_Forums tr:nth-child(even)
#MainTable_Forums tr:nth-child(odd)
```

These are being used for the inner `tr` as ID rules bind tighter than class rules.

You can also insert a `<tbody>` in the the HTML and then use these for the striping:

```
#MainTable_Forums > tbody > tr:nth-child(even)
#MainTable_Forums > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd)
```

Some browsers will insert the `<tbody>` for you so you'll need to have it in the selectors and the HTML to, hopefully, cover all the cases. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/b6zEy/

Depending on your specific needs you could replace your inner `tr` rule with this:

```
.ThreadInfo_Container td
```

to apply the style directly to the `td`. The effect isn't quite the same but it might, depending on your specific situation, work better; some browsers make a mess of borders on `tr` elements, some are fine with it. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/a4LEg/

Comment: i seem to have sucess with this so far from what i can see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The selector for the inner table is less [*specific*](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than the one(s) for the outer table, hence the styles of the outer table have precedence. You can make the selector for the inner table more specific like so:

```
#MainTable_Forums .ThreadInfo_Container tr { ... }
```

Comment: i just tried it before and got no result. Weird. Thanks though